# Detecting collisions in NetLogo

Tags: collision-detection, netlogo

**Hello. 
I'm working on a collision detection function in netlogo, collision occurs in my case if more than 3 turtles are on the same patch. 
So I applied this small piece of code to the move function to count the number of collisions:**

> ```
>  if count turtles-on patch-ahead 1 > 3 [
>     set numberOfCollsions numberOfCollsions + 1 ] ;
> ```

Unfortunately it doesn't work! How am I supposed to calculate them.

Thank you

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", do you mean you are getting an error message, unexpected behavior or what? Please elaborate. If there is an error message, please include it in full.

Comment: By saying it doesn't work I meant it doesn't count correctly. any suggestions of a better approach to count collisions?

Comment: The definition of “correctly” is up to you. The definition of “collision” is up to you. “It doesn’t count correctly” is essentially no improvement on “it doesn’t work”.